# Identification on a vague memory of a golden tomb and a stagecoach chase

Tags: story-identification, movie

About a year ago (late May 2020, I think), I saw a show or movie on TV. I watched a little bit of it, then changed the channel. That was right about the time I began to really like *Indiana Jones*, and as the movie/show kind of had that vibe, I later wanted to know what it was. All I can remember about it is:

1. It was live action.
2. There were some people in a tomb, and in the tomb was a short flight of stairs leading up to a golden coffin. They might have been about to open the coffin, but I can't be sure. I think there may have been some things swinging around from the ceiling (like traps), too.
3. I remember that after being in the room the people (I can't remember how many) were galloping quickly down a street in a stagecoach (it might have been something else, but I remember it as a stagecoach) and fighting with some other people on another stagecoach (again, I can't be sure.)

Of the age I only know this: It could have been anywhere from the 1980's to the present. But again, I'm not great at identifying things like that, so don't trust me too much there.

Comment: Do you have any sense of how old the movie or show was? Like which decade it might've been made in?

Comment: @LogicDictates Not really. It could have been anywhere from the 1980's to present. But again, I'm not great at identifying things like that.

Comment: was the *tomb* golden or just the coffin?

Comment: @NKCampbell I think it might have been a normal old stone tomb, but the coffin had lots of treasures and things around it.

Comment: *Young Indiana Jones* had a very similar vibe to the Indiana Jones films. For obvious reasons.

Comment: Was [Brendan Fraser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Fraser) in it?

Answer (score 15):

I’m pretty sure this is the 1983 3-d “spaghetti” action film released by Cannon as Raiders of the Lost Ark knockoff: *Treasure of the Four Crowns*
https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0084781/

It shares multiple scenes as described, including a stagecoach scene, the tomb, the treasure coffin and the swinging things.

The swinging traps played into the 3-d conceit.

Comment: This still looks better than Crystal Skull.

Comment: @Valorum It is!

Comment: Someone [put the whole thing on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XJCz9v0_7c). It probably avoided the "worst movies of all time" lists by being obscure.

Comment: @Machivity I’m not sure I’m proud or ashamed to say, but I saw this in Chicago area theater on initial release (then I also saw Crystal Skull in theater too). As far as I recall, it had wide release but bombed; I remember the trailer running on TV ads constantly. Ebert ran a review: https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/treasure-of-the-four-crowns-1983 He kind of liked it.